# Remove Unique Permission for specific folder and files

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I would like to delete/remove unique permission for one folder and its items using pnp-powershell

Example: Shared Documents

Folder1 - remove permission
--subfolder - remove permission (also subfolder files)
--subFolder2 - remove permission (also subfolder files)
--files - remove permission

[image]

Comment: I haven’t used pnp power shell before, but googled “pnp powershell folder permissions” and came across this, there seem to be quite a lot of code samples and explanations there:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpfolderpermission?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: @user1063287 Thank you for the suggestion, i have googled for pnp powershell for remove permission either i end up for only folders or all items in the library. But i need to choose only one folder within shared documents and within that one folder and its subfolders also files and files

Comment: You can edit it right in the site settings page, just make sure you are not inheriting permissions from parent web and you can edit them.

Comment: I guess i have to avoid manual changes, as i have huge number of folders like 100 or more and lot of files. Powershell to choose the folders would be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run the below PowerShell script as an admin:

```
#Set Variables
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$ListName = "Documents"
$FolderURL = "/Shared Documents/Test"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Function to reset permissions of all Sub-Folders
Function Reset-SubFolderPermissions($FolderURL)
{
    #Get all sub-folders of the Folder - Exclude system folders
    $SubFolders = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderURL -ItemType Folder 
 
    #Loop through each sub-folder
    ForEach($SubFolder in $SubFolders)
    {
        $SubFolderURL = $FolderUrl+"/"+$SubFolder.Name
        Write-host -ForegroundColor Green "Processing Folder '$($SubFolder.Name)' at $SubFolderURL"
 
        #Get the Folder Object - with HasUniqueAssignments and ParentList properties
        $Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $SubFolderURL -Includes ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments, ListItemAllFields.ParentList, ListItemAllFields.ID
 
        #Get the List Item of the Folder
        $FolderItem = $Folder.ListItemAllFields

        #Get all list items in the SubFolder
        $FolderServerRelativeUrl="/sites/sitename"+$SubFolderURL
        $Files = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -FolderServerRelativeUrl $FolderServerRelativeUrl

        #Iterate through each list item
        ForEach($File in $Files){
       
            #Check if the Item has unique permissions
            $HasUniquePermissions = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $File -Property "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"

            If($HasUniquePermissions){     
              
                $Msg = "Deleting Unique Permissions on {0} '{1}' at {2} " -f $File.FileSystemObjectType,$File.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"],$File.FieldValues["FileRef"]
                Write-host $Msg

                #Delete unique permissions on the list item
                Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $ListName -Identity $File.ID -InheritPermissions
            }
        }

        #Check if the Folder has unique permissions
        If($FolderItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments){

            #Reset permission inheritance
            Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $FolderItem.ParentList -Identity $FolderItem.ID -InheritPermissions
            Write-host "`tUnique Permissions are removed from the Folder!"
        }
 
        #Call the function recursively
        Reset-SubFolderPermissions $SubFolderURL
    }
}
   
#Call the function
Reset-SubFolderPermissions $FolderURL
```

[image]

[image]

========================== **Updated Answer** ========================

You need to modify this code in the PowerShell script:

```
#Get all list items in the SubFolder 
$FolderServerRelativeUrl="/sites/sitename"+$SubFolderURL
```

The **"/sites/sitename"** is your $SiteURL

**For example:**

$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test111"

$FolderServerRelativeUrl="/sites/test111"+$SubFolderURL

========================= `Update Answer` ========================

Please run the below script as an admin:

```
#Set Variables
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/CoupangCareCenter"
$ListName = "Documents"
$FolderURL = "/Shared Documents/Test"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

#Function to reset permissions of all Sub-Folders
Function Reset-FolderPermissions($FolderURL){

    #Get the Folder - with HasUniqueAssignments and ParentList properties
    $RootFolder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $FolderURL -Includes ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments, ListItemAllFields.ParentList, ListItemAllFields.ID
    
    #Get the List Item of the Folder
    $RootFolderItem = $RootFolder.ListItemAllFields

    $Items = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -FolderServerRelativeUrl "/sites/CoupangCareCenter/Shared Documents/Test"

    #Iterate through each list item
    ForEach($Item in $Items){
       
        #Check if the Item has unique permissions
        $ItemHasUniquePermissions = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $Item -Property "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"

            If($ItemHasUniquePermissions){     
              
                $ItemMsg = "Deleting Unique Permissions on {0} '{1}' at {2} " -f $Item.FileSystemObjectType,$Item.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"],$Item.FieldValues["FileRef"]
                Write-host $ItemMsg

                #Delete unique permissions on the list item
                Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $ListName -Identity $Item.ID -InheritPermissions
            }
        }
 
    #Check if the Folder has unique permissions
    If($RootFolderItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments){
        #Reset permission inheritance
        Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $RootFolderItem.ParentList -Identity $RootFolderItem.ID -InheritPermissions
        Write-host "Unique Permissions are removed from the Folder!"
    }

    Reset-FolderPermissions $FolderURL
 }
 
#Function to reset permissions of all Sub-Folders
Function Reset-SubFolderPermissions($FolderURL)
{
    #Get all sub-folders of the Folder - Exclude system folders
    $SubFolders = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderURL -ItemType Folder 
 
    #Loop through each sub-folder
    ForEach($SubFolder in $SubFolders)
    {
        $SubFolderURL = $FolderUrl+"/"+$SubFolder.Name
        Write-host -ForegroundColor Green "Processing Folder '$($SubFolder.Name)' at $SubFolderURL"
 
        #Get the Folder Object - with HasUniqueAssignments and ParentList properties
        $Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $SubFolderURL -Includes ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments, ListItemAllFields.ParentList, ListItemAllFields.ID
 
        #Get the List Item of the Folder
        $FolderItem = $Folder.ListItemAllFields

        #Get all list items in the SubFolder
        $FolderServerRelativeUrl="/sites/CoupangCareCenter"+$SubFolderURL
        $Files = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -FolderServerRelativeUrl $FolderServerRelativeUrl

        #Iterate through each list item
        ForEach($File in $Files){
       
            #Check if the Item has unique permissions
            $HasUniquePermissions = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $File -Property "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"

            If($HasUniquePermissions){     
              
                $Msg = "Deleting Unique Permissions on {0} '{1}' at {2} " -f $File.FileSystemObjectType,$File.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"],$File.FieldValues["FileRef"]
                Write-host $Msg

                #Delete unique permissions on the list item
                Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $ListName -Identity $File.ID -InheritPermissions
            }
        }

        #Check if the Folder has unique permissions
        If($FolderItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments){

            #Reset permission inheritance
            Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $FolderItem.ParentList -Identity $FolderItem.ID -InheritPermissions
            Write-host "`tUnique Permissions are removed from the Folder!"
        }
 
        #Call the function recursively
        Reset-SubFolderPermissions $SubFolderURL
    }
}
   
#Call the function
Reset-SubFolderPermissions $FolderURL

Reset-FolderPermissions $FolderURL
```

[image]

**Note:** Please modify these parameters in the script

$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"

$ListName = "Documents"

$FolderURL = "/Shared Documents/Root_Folder"

$Items = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -FolderServerRelativeUrl "/sites/sitename/Shared Documents/Root_Folder"

$FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/sites/sitename"+$SubFolderURL

Comment: The script throws error on the serverrelative url, i have attached the error message

Comment: Hi striker92. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi EchoDu, i tested it works great with the subfolders thank you but it does not work for parent folder. like "Test" folder under Shared Documents. Under "Test" folder it works for sub folders files and sub sub folders. Along with Subfolders and files even "Test" folder should delete unique permission

Comment: Hi striker92. I have modified the script. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Perfect, It works as expected ! Just figured that it does not exist script when it deletes the permission.